# How to remove the urlbar/navigator bar of the Iceweasel 29.0.1?

Tags: linux, firefox, vimperator, iceweasel

I just updated my Iceweasel on Debian Jessie. The current version number is 29.0.1. I like using `vimperator` which does not work well with a navigator bar because the navigator bar always catch the cursor automatically.

I tried to find solutions in the preferences but failed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
:set gui+=nonavigation
```

to hide the navigation bar. At least that's working with firefox 29.

You can add the line (without the `:`) in your `~/.vimperatorrc`.

See the help for more details.